# I need to make folders inside folders for each csv name that I find

Tags: powershell, object, foreach

csv file contain:

```
Name
A2846
B2846

I already have this folders            I need this folders 
      c:\A2846\                         c:\A2846\local\status\month\state\ 
      c:\B2846\                         c:\B2846\local\status\month\state\
```

*emphasized text*code:

Comment: What if there is a name in the CSV and a folder with that name does not exist? Create it new and add the subfolders in it aswell?

Comment: I wanted to look like this c:\B2846\local\status\month\state\ and if it doesn't have the folders i want to be able to create it then

Comment: @EnriqueTellez put your comment to your question. Because it belongs there and shows your effort as well. Show your current output & codes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Wit PowerShell it is very easy to create folders.

In your case just do

```
Import-Csv -Path '<yourCSVfile.csv>' | ForEach-Object {
    $folderPath = 'C:\{0}\local\status\month\state' -f $_.Name
    if (!(Test-Path -Path $folderPath -PathType Container)) {
        Write-Host "Creating path '$folderPath'"
        $null = New-Item -Path $folderPath -ItemType Directory
    }
}
```

Change `<yourCSVfile.csv>` to point to the the csv with the foldernames in it